# Difficulty with python prime number check

Tags: python, primes

I've been trying to get this code to work to return a input number as prime between 2 and 49, but all it does is return most numbers as prime, even when they aren't... For the exercise, I was given that 3, 5 and 7 were prime anyway, so just ignore that bit...

```
def prime(a):
if a < 2: return False
if a % 2 == 0: return False
if a == 3 or a == 5 or a == 7: return True
for n in range(3,int(a ** 0.5) + 1): 
    if a % n == 0: return False
    if a % n != 0: return True

a = input("Enter a number between 1 and 49: ")

if prime(a) is False:
    print a, " is not a prime number"

if prime(a) is True:
    print a, " is a prime number"
```

Comment: This isn't the algorithm you're using, but it's interesting and related: There's a probabilistic test for primes, that uses Fermat's Little Theorem (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_primality_test). You have to get up to 1729 to find a number that passes the test relative to 2, 3, and 5 but isn't prime. (And there are only four such < 10000).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for n in range(3,int(a ** 0.5) + 1): 
    if a % n == 0: return False
    if a % n != 0: return True  # This if condition is not needed
```

You don't need that 2nd if condition. else it will immediately return when the number is not divisible by current value of `n`. But you don't want that. You need to check for the next value if the current `n` cannot divide your number.

So, just remove that if, and add a `return True` after the loop ends..

So, **your `prime()` method** should be like this: -

```
def prime(a):
    if a < 2: return False
    if a % 2 == 0: return False
    if a == 3 or a == 5 or a == 7: return True
    for n in range(3,int(a ** 0.5) + 1): 
        if a % n == 0: return False

    return True
```